# SQL Server: Add seconds to a datetime field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This should be a softball for you SQL guys. I know I can add to an int field with something like `UPDATE tblUser SET Total=(Total+2)` but what is the syntax for adding seconds to a datetime field?

I'm using SQLServer 2008

Answer (score 107, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbluser SET DateField = DATEADD(ss,numOfSeconds,DateField)
```

Note the first parameter "ss".  This shows that you are adding seconds to the date.

[Check the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) for more info.

Comment: What are valid values for numOfSeconds?

Answer (score 14):

You should look into [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

`DATEADD (datepart , number , date)`

or the full update syntax

`UPDATE tbl SET YourDateField = DATEADD (ss, 2, YourDateField)`

Answer (score 0):

Updated additional answer for Google surfers, 2023. If you're getting syntax errors from the other answers.

Using MySQL version 8+.

```
UPDATE table_name SET some_datetime_column_name = DATE_ADD(some_datetime_column_name, INTERVAL 10 SECOND) WHERE some_other_column_name = 'something';
```