# SQL Query between two dates from sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to filter my result by two columns from sub query,so I have join them like below which works fine.

```
select * from EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA LEFT JOIN 
(
   Select DocumentID, LogDate
   From [LM_StateEvents]
   Where 1=1

) table2
ON 
   EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA.LLObjID=table2.DocumentID
   AND EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA.StatusDate = table2.LogDate 
WHERE table2.DocumentID IS NOT NULL
```

However the `EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA.StatusDate` in main query is not going to be the same value from sub query.It would have maximum of +5 seconds difference.  So I have to search like using between `table2.LogDate` and `table2.LogDate + 5 seconds`.

How can I achieve this.

Below is the sample data and Expected output.

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and esired results.

Comment: Why are you joining to a subquery instead of the table? And why bother with 1 = 1??

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated with sample Data and desired result.

Comment: @SeanLange 1=1 is just a placeholder to put the actual where condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `DATEDIFF` to make sure the difference does not exceed 5 seconds:

```
select * from EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA LEFT JOIN 
(
   Select DocumentID, LogDate
   From [LM_StateEvents]
   Where 1=1

) table2
ON 
   EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA.LLObjID=table2.DocumentID
   AND DATEDIFF(second,EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA.StatusDate,table2.LogDate) between -5 and 5
WHERE table2.DocumentID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can greatly simplify this by joining to the table instead of making a subquery and joining to that. Also, you should use an inner join instead of a left join because your where predicate is changing it into an inner join. I don't condone using functions like this in your join predicates because they are nonSARGable. You should probably fix the design so you don't have to do this. But given the current tables as you have them you can do something like this.

```
select * 
from EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA  rd
JOIN LM_StateEvents se on rd.LLObjID = se.DocumentID
   AND abs(datediff(second, rd.StatusDate = se.LogDate)) <= 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `cross apply`:

```
select srd.*, le.*
from EDM_STATUS_REPORT_DATA src cross apply
     (Select DocumentID, LogDate
      From LM_StateEvents le
      where le.LLObjID = srd.DocumentID and
            le.LogDate  = src.StatusDate 
     ) le
where le.DocumentID is not null;
```

Note:  Your outer `where` clause suggests that you need a match.  I wonder why you are using an outer join in that case.

Comment: . . . This lateral join will equivalent to `INNER JOIN`. SO, filter is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this answer here to add seconds to a date (use DateADD function): https://stackoverflow.com/a/3480794/6601237